# zsh - how to reference a variable that was dynamically named after multiple other variables?

Tags: shell, scripting, zsh

Consider the following zsh script:

```
#! /bin/zsh

key1="a"
key2="b"

declare ${key1}_${key2}="c"

echo $a_b                       # this prints 'c' as expected
echo ${(P)${key1}_${key2}}      # Bad substitution
```

As you can see, I am confused about the syntax in the last line. How can I reference the variable `a_b` using the contents of `$key1`and `$key2`?

Also, would this work if `a_b` was an array, as in `declare -a ${key1}_${key2}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man zshexpn` provides a list of 25(!) rules that govern how expansions are processed. The problem here is that `${key1}_$key2` isn't joined into a single word until step 23, while `(P)` is applied much earlier. You need a nested expansion to produce a single word upon which `(P)` can be applied. To do that, you can use the `:-` operator, which can omit a parameter name, expanding instead to whatever default value you provide.

```
% print ${:-${key1}_$key2}
a_b
```

Since nested substitutions are step 1 of the process, the above expression can fill in for the name expected by `(P)` in step 4.

```
% print ${(P)${:-${key1}_$key2}}
c
```